# Show edit comment information

Tags: comments, edit

I'm currently working on an enterprise website to manage internal information about clients. Some parts have comment sections allowing users to write comments about a certain client, I was asked to add an "edit comment" functionality, but besides showing the creation information (author and date) I have to show the updater info (author and date) a comment can be edited by a manager. So I was wondering how to show two dates and possibly two authors in the header of a comment and not to confuse user and show in a hierarchical way.

Thanks so so much for your help :)

**Edit:** Thanks to Pectoralis Major's answer I ended up with something like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By not placing them next to each other and using color and text-size to create visual hierarchy.

Just a quick example since i don't know how your website looks:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can see similar feature in ux.stackoverflow or any other community driven applications. Have a look at below link. You will notice two entries just after the questions

1: Edited by, date and time

2: Asked by, date and time.

You may follow the same design pattern in your application.

[accordions vs tabs](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/accordions-vs-tabs/60594#60594)