# Use tabs or just present all the content out in an accordion?

Tags: navigation, tabs, accordion

For a design project, we are deciding whether **using a tab within the accordion** or **just lay out the data with subtitles within the accordion** will best help categorize the content for the user.

What do you guys think is the best practice?

[image: Accordion with just content presented]

[image: Accordion with tabs]

Answer (score 2):

Honest answer is - **It depends on the amount of information, how you want your users to see the information and width-height of the interface**

I was writing in details, but I'd rather choose this answer which can give you a clear idea in details, and the answer is much more informative.

[accordions vs tabs](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/accordions-vs-tabs)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690589/difference-between-accordion-and-tabs

Hope that will help :)

Answer (score 1):

### Ask yourself: Do users need to see all content in one page or at a glance? Do the tabs represent categories?

**Tabs (Used to ease navigation and group related content):**

- Are you categorizing or logically grouping the content?
- Are you trying to discourage vertical scrolling in case there is a lot of content vertically displayed?

**No Tabs (It is better to group all content in one page):**

- Content does not need to be categorized or separated on different views  (I just need to display related content).
- Users would benefit from seeing all content on one page or at a glance.
- There is no concerns of long vertical scrolling, instead it is encouraged.

**Remember:**

**Tabs** provide a more **organized structure** especially when there is a need to **separate** the content! **But** if it is best for content to be **grouped on one** long page that **encourages scrolling**, then **no Tabs!**